# View disk utilization / activity

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage

Is there a way in android to view the disk usages of apps as they are running?  I currently suspect that one of my applications is writing to the disk a lot which is slowing my phone down.  I am looking for something similar to the windows performance monitor that can show disk reads and writes by programs.

Comment: I think the only way to properly answer is https://www.xda-developers.com/check-io-usage-iotop-android/amp/ , it requires root and special kernel build config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Perfmon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.perfmon), is a paid app that fits that well and is AFAIK the only app that gives these kind of details (closest to Windows performance monitor), for **app running in foreground**. It creates a floating window to give details about

> - CPU
> - Disk I/O
> - Network I/O

I especially like the CPU capacity usage, which takes into account all the cores present and calculates, "effective usage". This coupled with RAM usage effectively helped me weed out some battery and memory hogging apps

**Edit**: I was searching for a similar approach using command line but nothing turned up

[image]

Comment: This doesnt pinpoint the offending app  :(. Simole system monitor shows overall too