# what kind of apps can cause high I/O?

Tags: lagging

The problem is high IO, mainly read 50 to 150 MB/s (shows always as 100% tho), for about one minute of despair, lowering the quality of the android realm user experience.

The only way to know for sure, would be https://www.xda-developers.com/check-io-usage-iotop-android/amp/

So, i would need root and a specially compiled kernel (rom?).

But, if you could hint me, mainly if yours have an iotop like app, it could be enough.

Android 6.0.1

I tried stopping gallery, i thought it was scanning media, didnt help.

During high IO, i saw zygote, /system/bin/installd, system_server  use a bit cpu but on top of the list, but that is a proccess, not an app (that we could stop).

I use simple system monitor app.

And i need to know HINTs of the app/proccess, not the overall IO neither what specific proccess here is causing trouble (as hints may suffice), so I can try stopping them by chance.

Thats why my question differs from: [View disk utilization / activity](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132659/view-disk-utilization-activity) (also the accepted answer there doesnt answer about showing specific proccess IO, that is in the body of the question, therefore the accepted is just a partial answer).

Comment: Typically a process with a lot of IO activity also shows a significant amount of CPU usage. That would be the first way to identify the problematic process.

Comment: Here, the mentioned processes use each less than 4%. If im not wrong, on linux at least, a proccess with low cpu usage could still be the source of high IO right? as both are similar